# How does JavaFX handle cyclic property bindings?

Tags: javafx, binding

Assume I have the following code snippet:

```
        private final BooleanProperty a = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        private final BooleanProperty b = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        private final BooleanProperty c = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        private final BooleanProperty d = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

        a.bind(c);
        c.bind(d.or(a));
```

How does JavaFX handle that? Because a is dependent from c, 
but c is dependent on d or a). Is there a formula to recognize such 'exceptions'?

my first thought would be that a property_a cant be bound to another property_b that is bound to property_a or depends on properties too, that have properties bound to property_a. right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaFX does not prevent this kind of dependency.
There could be no cycle in the dependencies and in this case to be allowed. Analyzing the dependencies is not possible, since `bind` takes `ObservableValue` as parameter, regardless of the implementation and the internals of the implementation are hidden "behind the interface", so it's impossible to get the dependencies from the `ObservableValue`.
It's therefore up to the programmer to ensure no circular dependency is created.

Modifying `d` just leads to a `StackOverflowError`.

You can identify this kind of issue, if you analyze the "depends on" relation (the transitive closure needs to be irreflexive), but you need to store the information about the dependencies in a custom data structure (or analyze it "by hand" before compiling).

A directed graph would be suitable to store this kind of information and assuming you prevent any circular dependencies from being established, you can do a depth first search of the dependencies for the property you want to bind. (DFS is enough, since the dependency graph is a forest.)

in your case after `a.bind(c)`

graph would contain a single edge:

```
a -> c
```

before doing `c.bind(d.or(a))` you need to search the nodes `d` and `a` for dependencies to `c`, since you want to add the following edges:

```
c -> d
c -> a
```

Now `d` isn't bound, but you can go from `a` to `c`, which is the `Property` you want to bind to, so this dependency should not be created.